# Issue with CSS working with Rails 3.2 and SASS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, sass

I'm starting a new website using Rails 3.2, but I can't get the CSS to make the page occupy the full browser window. But there is an issue: I can't get the height to fill the page, it always fills just the necessary.

I've tried everything possible to achieve this, I even used the exact same CSS I had for another Rails site I made some time ago (with Rails 3.0.5, without SASS), but it just won't work, the height either don't fill the screen or overflows it, creating a scrollbar when it shouldn't.

Maybe SASS is the problem here? I'm using a few mixins for gradients, rounded borders, nothing too big.

The current CSS I have is this (only the important parts):

```
html {
  @include no_space;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

root {
  @include no_space;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

body {
  @include no_space;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  /*    top: 0px;*/
  font-family: "Helvetica", Verdana, Arial;
  color: $text_color;
  background-color: $background;
}

.site {
  @include gradient(white, $background);
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

The no_space mixin contains just the 2 lines saying that margins and paddings are 0.

If I add "height: 100%" to the body here, the page overflows the equivalent of the footer space. And btw the .site div contains the actual website, and is child of body, the footer div is also direct child of body.

Oh, and no, there is no other CSS file messing up with mine, I double checked that with Firebug

Comment: Have you tried reducing the percentage height on your .site div? Try with height less then 100% and see if that solution fits.  I don't think its SASS-specific thing.

Comment: I don't want to resource to calculating percentages, I've made a handful of websites just like this before and all of them worked fine, but if I can't get another method to do this I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making `body`'s height to `100%`:

```
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yes, and as I said, when I do that the page overflows and the footer is not visible anymore

Comment: @RodrigoCastro rather than showing the SASS source code, show the CSS generated by SASS. That would be more helpful.